# Отсутствует перевод уведомления о внесённой правке

Tags: дефект, локализация, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Внёс правку, улучшающую оформление кода в вопросе, а в ответ получил уведомление, которое не очень соответствует требованиям сайта «Stack Overflow на **русском**»

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17377

В текст сообщения добавили точку в конце предложения и перевод слетел. Взял текст из [старой ревизии](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14176).

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2022.1.7.41110